# Passer-by view of my garden - improvements?

Tags: plant-recommendations, design

What you see here is the view of a passer-by to a corner of my garden. It turned to be nice this year, with the addition of echinacea (light purple flower) and cosmos (dark purple flowers). In the background, there is a group of thuja sunkists.

[image]

Do you have any ideas for further improvement of the view, for the next year?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fantastic question.  You need something with coarse texture, huge texture.  Have you ever seen Gunnera?  Dinosaur Food?  [image: Gunnera]  I've never seen it this large, but close.  Your flowers would be very happy with this guy as a 'body guard'?  Lots of other ideas but this is the one that came to mind and would definitely slow people down at the corner!

Comment: Great idea!!!! I was considering Inula helenium, also large leafs, but not even close to gunnera...

Comment: These pictures show gunnera way larger than I have ever seen in reality. Petasites japonicus or Coltsfoot.  I loved this plant.  Is this area very sunny, protected?  Or does it get partial shade?  How funny that we are on the same dang page!  I've got to go see Inula...

Comment: I think Inula is in the picture with the gunnera I sent!  If this area is partial shade with plenty of moisture and protection...I've got lots of great plants...Ligularia, Rocket?

Comment: Wow, yes, inula is in the photo too, I didnt notice... Some special kind. The photo is of a large leaf lover.

Comment: The area is sunny.

Comment: Gunnera: "The stalks of many species are edible"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunnera

Comment: I think Gunnera would do well in that spot.  As Wayfaring says it is actually edible!  Other large leaved plants do better in the shade.  Gunnera, as you will find has very thick, prickly leaves.  Loves the full sun but does well in partial shade.